# Using std::bind with __stdcall function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdcall, stdbind

How does one can use std::bind (not boost::bind) on __stdcall function or is it even possible in current implementation?
When i try to compile following example:

```
std::function<LRESULT __stdcall(int, WPARAM, LPARAM)> func;
func = std::bind(&EventListener::myhook, this, std::placeholders::_1, 
                 std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
```

or same but with declaring func as:

```
std::function<LRESULT(int, WPARAM, LPARAM> func;
```

Gives me strange build output (which i included below). There is a very sick way to make it compile:

```
decltype(std::bind(&EventListener::myhook, nullptr, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3))* HookCallbackPointer;
    HookCallbackPointer proc;

proc = reinterpret_cast<HookCallbackPointer>
    (&std::bind(&EventListener::myhook, this,
                std::placeholders::_1,
                std::placeholders::_2,
                std::placeholders::_3));
```

But it won't let me call function like this (*proc)(0,0,0);. Which is sad. 
All this happens just because that func - myhook - declared as __stdcall. Offcourse i can just write a dirty assembly hack that will push 4 dwords at the end of func and this will "make" it __stdcall, but i'm not quite sure about this and also this is even more sicker way.

```
1>D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\xrefwrap(431): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced,_Ret,_Funx,_Btuple,_Ftuple>::type' to 'LRESULT'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=false,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Funx=__w64 long (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),
1>              _Btuple=std::tuple<EventListener *,std::_Ph<1>,std::_Ph<2>,std::_Ph<3>>,
1>              _Ftuple=std::tuple<int &,WPARAM &,LPARAM &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(239) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<_Ty>::_ApplyX<_Rx,int,__w64 unsigned int,__w64 long>(_V0_t &&,_V1_t &&,_V2_t &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Rx=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(239) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<_Ty>::_ApplyX<_Rx,int,__w64 unsigned int,__w64 long>(_V0_t &&,_V1_t &&,_V2_t &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Rx=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(239) : while compiling class template member function 'LRESULT std::_Func_impl<_Callable,_Alloc,_Rx,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>::_Do_call(_V0_t &&,_V1_t &&,_V2_t &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Callable=_MyWrapper,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<LRESULT,int,WPARAM,LPARAM>>,
1>              _Rx=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(516) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl<_Callable,_Alloc,_Rx,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Callable=_MyWrapper,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<LRESULT,int,WPARAM,LPARAM>>,
1>              _Rx=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(516) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<LRESULT,int,WPARAM,LPARAM>>,
1>              _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(516) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<LRESULT,int,WPARAM,LPARAM>>,
1>              _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(516) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<LRESULT,int,WPARAM,LPARAM>>
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(516) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<LRESULT,int,WPARAM,LPARAM>>
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(692) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          D:\bin\Visual Studio\VC\include\functional(692) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=LRESULT,
1>              _V0_t=int,
1>              _V1_t=WPARAM,
1>              _V2_t=LPARAM,
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>,
1>              _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(27) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty> &std::function<_Fty>::operator =<std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=LRESULT (int,WPARAM,LPARAM),
1>              _Forced=false,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),
1>              _V0_t=EventListener *const ,
1>              _V1_t=std::_Ph<1> &,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Ph<2> &,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Ph<3> &,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil,
1>              _Fx=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(27) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty> &std::function<_Fty>::operator =<std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=LRESULT (int,WPARAM,LPARAM),
1>              _Forced=false,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),
1>              _V0_t=EventListener *const ,
1>              _V1_t=std::_Ph<1> &,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Ph<2> &,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Ph<3> &,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil,
1>              _Fx=std::_Bind<false,void,LRESULT (__stdcall EventListener::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM),EventListener *const ,std::_Ph<1> &,std::_Ph<2> &,std::_Ph<3> &,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>
1>          ]
```

Comment: You assume that the result of `std::bind` is `std::function<LRESULT __stdcall(int, WPARAM, LPARAM)>`. The compiler doesn't seem to agreee on that. The standard says that the type is unspecified, so how do you know what it will be?

Comment: Extending what Bo said, while the function that is ultimately called is `__stdcall`, the bound object will have an `operator()` that need not be `__stdcall`. I don't really know whether/how this is handled in `std::bind`, but I would not expect the bound object to be `__stdcall` (i.e. the calling convention of `operator()` and the call that is performed internally need not match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In current VS 2012 its not possible and anyway not applicable as solution to this problem. 
The idea was to bind member function and use it as Hook-procedure. That is not possible, as David Rodriguez and R. Martinho Fernandes (in chat - lounge-C++) mentioned, because std::bind produces object, not function and thus it's result can't be passed as argument to SetWindowsHookEx.